# Take picture from streaming video

Tags: android, android-camera

I need to take a picture from the mobile phone while its camera is open.
Actually, I need that picture for face recognition. I will take a picture, I will detect a face and then post it to a web API (I am using ayonix webapi 1.3 https://market.mashape.com/felx/ayonix-webapi-1-3)
On my Android application I can invoke a service with images on its storage. So the service part is ok. Now I need to get an image while the camera is open.

Is it possible, and if so how? I could not find any tutorials.